# FFMPEG - Image extraction stretch problem

Tags: image, ffmpeg, scale

I have a .mov video file with 1440x1080 resolution. I extracted the frames from the video, using scale `-vf scale=1440:-1` but the images are stretched. Even though, the dimension of the extracted images are 1440x1080, the image is stretched on the height dimension and doesn't match the aspect ratio of the video.

How can I solve this issue?

Here is the output from FFMPEG for the original video:

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: qtrle (rle  / 0x20656C72), rgb24(progressive), 1440x1080, 624445 kb/s, SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn (default)
```

Comment: The problem is in the aspect ratio - that 1440x1080 resolution has probably the other ratio than the video has for real. Use `ffmpeg -i input.mov` and look for `SAR` and `DAR` values (or share the output of this command with us) - these two values will tell you what aspect ratio you need to use to scale the output image.

Comment: Hi, I have added the FFMPEG output on the original question. Also, here: Stream #0:0(eng): Video: qtrle (rle  / 0x20656C72), rgb24(progressive), 1440x1080, 624445 kb/s, SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn (default)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the value of `DAR` is `16:9` but `1440x1080` is not `16:9` then to generate the frames with "the proper" aspect ratio you should use `-vf scale=1920:1080` filter instead.

Comment: Thanks, this scale ratio worked perfectly. :)